# Sound Stops on Some Videos

Tags: windows-7, video, sound-card

I just reinstalled Windows 7 after my harddrive crashed. Installed all sound drivers and whatnot, but now when I'm playing some video files, audio will work for about 5 minutes, and then drop to almost nothing with a lot of background noise that shouldn't be with the video.

Tried re-installing sound card drivers (Sound Blaster X-FI PCI slot), and I think it's trying to update everytime I reboot, but fails and says that I already have a newer sound driver. This also does not fix the issue mentioned above.

This issue does seem to apply to all cases. Some youtube videos have audio that works all the way through. Some youtube videos sound distored and filled with static, which starts a couple of seconds after the beginning of the video.

I've had no problems with sound when in games such as GW2 and NFS. Vent also seems to work fine (inbound anyways. I don't have a mic for outbound).

Is there something wrong with the card itself? Or am I missing some audio codec or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was a driver issue. What was happening, which I didn't see before is that when I uninstalled the drivers, it was not deleting the drivers. I tried to uninstall the drivers again, and selected the option in Windows 7 to force delete the drivers after it was uninstalled.

After this, I rebooted, and installed the drivers from the package that was downloaded directly from the vendor's website. This fixed the issue.